# UNIX - simple - What is a relative-to-home pathname?

Tags: linux, unix, path, relative-path

I am aware of relative and absolute paths. What is a relative-to-home pathname? If I was in a directory, how would I navigate to a sibling directory using a relative-to-home pathname using `cd`?

Comment: In the form that you've posted it this is not a programming question. Ask on [unix.se]

Answer (score 1):

Home relative path name could be ~/ which points to your home directory.  ~/my_folder would be a path to my_folder that is in your home directory.  Now say you are doing something in /etc directory, so /etc is your current path.  If you would like to go to your home directory you type in cd ~/  If you want to go to my_folder in your home directory you type in cd ~/my_folder